# Django Join on none Primary Key solution

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Here's my models:

```
class Rate(models.Model)
    place_external_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Unavailability(models.Model)
    place_external_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

**place_external_id** is come from another standalone app.

I want to join thoses 2 models with a single query. I understand it's impossible in Django to JOIN on a non ForeignKey. Is there a way to change my model in something more "django friendly" ? or I have to go with RAW ?

Thanks for your help,
S.

Comment: A ForeignKey is just an integer field. Why can't you declare those fields as FKs?

Comment: I think I'll try with it. I don't know why I just don't think about put in this app another Place model (already one in another app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want them to be ForeignKey:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    #your fields

class Rate(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place')

class Unavailability(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place')
```

Comment: Place already exist on another app and I want to make each app standalone. But, when I think about it I can create a Place with just an external_id field and it's would work